# how to add border to image css on blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

My attempt to make the related post widget thumbnil image on blogger circle wasn't successful. Here's the code I am using..

```
.popular-posts .item-thumbnail {
border: 5px solid #dddddd !important; 
border-radius: 100px !important;
}
```

my blog, tipsontricks (dot) com, see the sidebar- I want the border to go on top of the image, not under. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: setting the border-radius on the actual image makes the corner rounded at least. Are the images always same size as the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mariusnn said, take those styles off `.item-thumbnail` and put them directly on the `img` and see if you like that effect better.